# Reading from an input and piping its content as output

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, command-line-interface

how should I proceed to create an output like this in bash with nodejs

> $ echo “Hello World” > foo.txt //creating the text file
>
> $ ./test < foo.txt // launching the test.js script with the text file as input
>
> Hello World //result

I've tried

test.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile('how to get foo.txt path enterd as input ?','utf8', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
  var array = data.toString().split("\n");
  for(i in array) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
 });
```

Comment: I got this solution "$./test.js  foo.txt " works but it's not perfect it dosen't parse the < foo.txt   "$./test.js< foo.txt " dosen't work



#!/usr/bin/env node
var userArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
var searchPattern = userArgs[0];
var fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile(searchPattern,'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
  var array = data.toString().split("\n");
  for(i in array) {
      console.log(array[i]);
     }
      });

Answer (score 0):

The script below will read the contents of foo.txt into the chunks variable.  When the stream is finished the contents will output to console.

```
//node thisFile.js foo.txt
//console.log(process.argv) will tell you what the CLI inputs are
fileName = process.argv[2];
input = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
var chunks = '';
input.on('data' , function(data){
    chunks += data;
});
input.on('end', function(){
    console.log('blow ' + chunks);
});
```

Is this what you're asking?

Comment: I need to get that foo text from the CLI

Comment: $./test.js < foo.txt

test.js 
                 `fileName = process.argv[2];
                  console.log(fileName);
`
I get undefined

Comment: so you aren't launching this via node then? traditionally it should read something like `node ./test.js foo.txt`

Comment: no it's from bash I've added `     #!/usr/bin/env node ` at the top of the node